# Some applications won't connect to the internet via 3G after rooting my phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, connection-issues, motorola-moto-g

I have initially a [Motorola moto g xt1039](http://www.phonemore.com/phone/motorola-moto-g-4g-xt1039/1837) with Android 4.4.4

I have rooted the phone by following [this guide](http://www.teamandroid.com/2014/09/06/root-moto-g-android-444-kitkat-superboot/).

The phone works normal, I am able to connect to the internet via Wi-Fi.

Some applications such as *Google Play* and *Twitter* are able to connect since I can install apps and refresh my *Twitter* feed by using the 3G connection.

I've been also able to ping to `8.8.8.8` and to `www.google.com` by using the terminal emulator.

Furthermore, sharing the 3G connection through Wi-Fi works as well, I've been able to use the shared connection from my Laptop PC.

**The very confusing problem is that** some applications such as chrome, firefox, Gmail, and Youtube are unable to connect when using the 3G connection.

These applications start, keep loading for a while and then show an error message, usually *"unable to load"* or *"connection timeout"*.

**What is going on here, how to troubleshoot this issue?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a bogus proxy was set for the Mobile Data Connection I was using.

**Removing the bogus proxy configuration solved the issue!**

Here is a guide to [Mobile data connection proxy setting](http://www.techverse.net/how-to-setup-proxy-server-3g-4g-data-connection-android-phone/).